# Joomla 1.6 -- Ready for a Production?

Tags: joomla

I am redesigning a business website and will be porting it into Joomla.  The functionality of the site will be fairly simple.  I would like to use Joomla 1.6.  Is the new version of Joomla at an acceptable stage for production?

Answer (score 1):

Yes Joomla 1.6 was offically released on the 10/01/2010.

These are the words from the Joomla site:

> As of 10 January 2011, Joomla! version 1.6.0 is available. This is a production version of Joomla.

From: http://www.joomla.org/component/content/article/5252.html

Comment: I have already been testing the new 1.6 release since Jan 10.  Actually I am wanting to find out if the Stack Exchange members think it is bug free (and has enough extensions available) to use in live sites.

Comment: There aren't very many extensions for 1.6. However having said that I suspect that certain 1.5 extensions excluding plugins (as many events have been renamed) could work if they don't use the global variable $mainframe which is now not supported in 1.6. In terms of bugs in 1.6 those should have all been resolved in the beta phase and there isn't anything major at the moment. Should there be then the Joomla team are pretty good at fixing those critical issues quite quickly and releasing a new version.